# Dojo - using <div> to move-to from one view to another in single html page

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, dojo

In Dojo mobile, how do you move from view 1 to view 2 when a div in view 1 is clicked?

For example, you have two views in a single html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- head stuff here -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="viewOne" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View">
        <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading">View One</h1>

        <div id="gotoViewTwo">Goto View Two</div>

    </div>
    <div id="viewTwo" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View">
        <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" back="Home" moveTo="viewOne">View Two</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So what I want to do is that when the div with id "gotoViewTwo" is clicked, I want to go to view two.

I am new to dojo, but I know jQuery Mobile very well if that helps you explaining to me what i need to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thre are a couple of ways, one is to use performTransition from the view.  Use the dijit registry to get the view and call its performtransition function. args 1. view transitioning to 2. direction of transition(left or right) 3. type of transition(slide, fade ....)

dijit.registry.byId("ViewOne").performTransition("ViewTwo",                     1, "slide");